# Updated To Craft 3, How To Delete Craft 2 Plugins

Tags: plugins, craft3

I moved from Craft 2 to 3 but some of the plugins I used at one-time and are no longer compatible with Craft 3.  Those old plugins are now ghosts.  Meaning they are listed in the database and some have their own tables.

How to best get rid of old Craft 2 plugins?

Comment: Which plugins specifically? It may vary based on the plugin.

Comment: Form Builder 2, AmForms, Hacksaw, Shortener are the main ones I see in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It partially depends on the plugin. The one guarantee you have is that there will be a row in the `plugins` table. Go ahead and delete that row.

Some plugins create 3rd party tables. For *most* of those plugins, it's probably safe to just delete those tables as well.

I know you can't go back in time, but... the *best* solution would have been to remove those plugins *before* updating. Virtually all Craft 2 plugins did a good job cleaning up after themselves in the database.

---

Based on your comment...

> "Form Builder 2, AmForms, Hacksaw, Shortener"

- **Form Builder 2** - Not very familiar with this, but looks like it has 5 tables. Probably safe to delete them.
- **AmForms** - Another one with 5 tables. Probably safe to delete these as well.
- **Hacksaw** - No DB tables
- **Shortener** - No DB tables

Comment: All cleaned, was hoping Venti was the cause of the clash with the Inventory Plugin but no dice.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you’re having issues with the Inventory plugin, hit me up on Craft Slack (@lindseydiloreto)

Comment: Awesome, will do.